# Any metal or chemical or any thing which repels Iron?

Tags: electromagnetism, physical-chemistry, metals

I on a project, i required a metal/chemically treated metal/Chemical/anything which repels iron and steel like two same side magnets do.

I searched in the internet and didn't found anything which repels iron and steel.

- what are the metals which repels iron and Steel?
- What are the chemicals or any treatment to metals which makes metal to repel iron and steel?

Answer (score 1):

You want [diamagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism): this is when a material is repelled by a magnetic field just as normal [ferromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism) materials are attracted to it. The two main problems are that diamagnetism is typically very weak compared to ferromagnetism (with the exception of superconductors), and that it sounds like you want the iron and steel to become repelled. But iron and steel are ferromagnetic by nature (with the exception of some alloys like stainless steel): they will always be attracted to magnets [as long as they have electrons with unpaired spins that can do exchange interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Origin_of_magnetism).

Of course, you could dissolve the metal into acid and get a compound that isn't magnetic, but this might be taking "chemical treatment" too far.

However, maybe it is possible to use a diamagnetic material to repel small grains of magnetised iron? Whether this works for your project depends a lot on how large pieces you work with and how much you need them repelled. In general I suspect it is far easier to try to design something that tries to attract the iron away from where you don't want it to be rather than repel it.

Comment: Hello @anders Sandberg,  yes my project is to repel needles but without magnetising it. from what i can make a metal like copper to repel unmagnetised and magnetised needles.? I know copper is a diamagnetic metal but not that strong to repel a needle.? How can i make it strong (to the maximum of it's strength) to repel a needle.?

Comment: I don't think you can get enough diamagnetism from copper to repel a normal needle, and that is when the needle itself is magnetized. Unmagnetized needles will not react to diamagnetic materials. I would rather look at placing a magnet on the side to drag the needles towards it and away from whatever they need to be away from. If handled right this may not magnetize the needles.

Comment: How about this video : https://youtu.be/b638sP1t5kU , look at this, I want to make some thing similar..

Comment: The video is some kind of fake. My guess would be that the "disk" is rather a box, and in this box there are small magnets on a spinning disk, or some electromagnetic setup with fluctuating fields. Other possibilities: those are not iron pins, but styrene pins with positive charge and the disk is negatively charged (styrene because for this lively movement with the small electrostatic forces you need something light);  Or: the whole setup is spinning around an axis  (the newspaper used to obscure moving background) and the pins are moved by centrifugal forces.

Comment: So you're saying we can't make a magnet repel a (previously magnetized) chunk of iron? I certainly saw magnets repelling each other via ferro/imagnetism. Why such a focus on diamagnetism?

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson - The question was not about pre-magnetized and aligned iron. Note the "like" in the initial sentence.